# Jquery changing all text to bold not succeeding text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am trying to implement a button that changes the font weight to bold.

I am currently using this code

```
    $('#new_shout_bold').on('click', function() {
        $('.dash_new_shout_textarea').toggleClass('bold');
        return false; // prevent navigation to #
});
```

The problem is that if i were to type some text and then click the bold button, all of the previous text gets converted to bold, how do i change the above code to only the text about to be written in bold and not the previous text?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `contenteditable=true`, you could call `document.execCommand("bold", false, "");`

```
 <input type="button" value="bold" 
                       onclick="document.execCommand('bold', false, '');"> 
 <div contenteditable="true">Can the text be in bold? Yes! 
                          mark and click the button! 
                          want to write in bold?
                          Click `bold` and start typing!</div>
```

check out this fiddle: jsfiddle.net/SpacePineapple/u6Ew6

For more built-in text editing options, I recommend you become familiar with this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla

**Edit**: also see https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/1096/using_the_html5_attribute_contenteditable_to_create_a_wysiwyg  and the sample at https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/1096/samples/try4.htm

Comment: How would I use your suggestion in my code just call the execCommand on click?

Comment: like this: `<input type="button" value="bold" onclick='document.execCommand("bold", false, "");'>` check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SpacePineapple/u6Ew6/

Comment: Also note that @TastySpaceApple is using a `div` with the `contenteditable` attribute set, and not a `textarea`.  There is no way to apply styles to portions of a textarea like a rich text editor.

Comment: ok thats brilliant, is it also possible to do this with a button for italic, underline and hyperlink?

Comment: it is. like so: `document.execCommand("italic", false, "");` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla for more possible commands.